# I came across these and cannot identify the set - greys, tan, orange, darker green

Tags: set-identification

I came across these and cannot identify the set.
Can anyone help me with identifying the set?

[image: greys, tan, orange, darker green]

Answer (score 8):

- The top left assembly is from [75974: Bastion](https://brickset.com/sets/75974-1/Bastion)
  [image]
- the top right assembly is [from one of these AT-ST 's](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=6589&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=2&itemNo2=92947&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=86&itemNo3=60478&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=11&in=S)
- the bottom left assembly is from [75035: Kashyyyk Troopers](https://brickset.com/sets/75035-1/Kashyyyk-Troopers)
  [image]
- The bottom right assembly is from [70228: Vultrix's Sky Scavenger](https://brickset.com/sets/70228-1/Vultrix-s-Sky-Scavenger)

[image]

Comment: [AT-ST 75153](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75153-1) is the only of the three to have [6587 in Dark Tan](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6587&idColor=69) and [92593 in LBG](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92593&idColor=86)